# Split single large image into multiple A4 pages

Tags: .net

Referring to the following thread [How to print one large image in many pages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14075844/how-to-print-one-large-image-in-many-pages?rq=1)

I got the image to be split in multiple pages but i need to adjust the width and height according A4 Size paper. How can it be done??

Comment: Isn't this the printer's driver responsibility?

Comment: width exceeds the paper size so the image is cut. Please help me on this

Comment: what I meant, is that the printer's driver, or the imaging software, should provide a "poster" print option.

Comment: Sorry! I do not get. Am new to this concept

Comment: @Iaiswarya - can you name the printer you're trying to output to?

Comment: Thank you sir for helping.Am using Samsung CLX-6200 Series PCL6, but am building this application for my client. They will be running the app across 900 stores in which printers will vary.

Answer (score 0):

With respect to some comments above, some printers have a 'poster print' option.  This would be in the printer settings that one would review after hitting 'print' on the application.  Not all printers do this.

The alternative is to use the System.Drawing library, import the image to a .BMP in memory, then slice off chunks into new BMPs.  First see if you can get the printer to do the dirty work, use this option only if A) you're not sure what printer is the destination for the output, or B) you're doing heavy duty graphics anyway and you'll be using this for other purposes.

[image: Poster Print Page]

If all the printers in your stores use PCL6, they would most likely support this mode consistently.  If not, you'll have to do it the hard way.

Comment: Thank you sir for helping.Am using Samsung CLX-6200 Series PCL6, but am building this application for my client. They will be running the app across 900 stores in which printers will vary.