# How to print all contents of panel control in multiple pages in winform using c#

Tags: c#, printing

I have a winform application that I want to print entire page, I have been able to print the page if is only a page. But I want to print all contents even if its more than 1 page. The contents contains datagridview that span up to 5 page long. So i want to be able to print the content with images datagridview text etc. Thanks in advance.

Comment: See the related questions on the right side of the page.

Answer (score 0):

The *correct* answer is that you don't. More precisely, you don't just print out a control. A control is drawn so that it looks good on the *screen*, which is much lower resolution than a printer. If you just dump a control's on-screen appearance to the printer, you'll end up with something very ugly. This kind of screen-dump "printing" is a hack at best, and it is certainly not something that should ever end up in a professional application.

Instead, you should write code that renders the *contents* of your control to a `PrintDocument` in an arrangement that looks pleasing on a piece of paper. This gives you much more control over the appearance of the printout, allowing you to handle things like the need to wrap onto multiple pages. And because you're doing the drawing at the full resolution of the printer, it won't look blurry and pixellated.

Of course, that takes work. Printing is one of the more difficult tasks in WinForms. The framework doesn't help you out very much. It is really something you have to write the code for yourself, because only you know what your printouts should look like.

So if you don't want to do the work, you go the ugly/lazy route and use the `DrawToBitmap` method of the control to render its on-screen contents to a bitmap. Then you send that bitmap to the printer. Which breaks if the bitmap is too large to fit on a single sheet of paper, as you've discovered. So you aren't getting out of writing some actual code either way you swing it. To go from here, you need to determine the space available on the paper, compare it to the size of the control's bitmap, and divide the bitmap up into page-sized sections. Once you've got the page-sized sections, you send each one to the printer as the contents of a new page. You'll find a detailed discussion, complete with sample code, for printing an image across multiple pages [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1113123/using-c-sharp-to-print-large-images-over-mulitple-pages). As I've said, the difference is that instead of loading a bitmap from file (as Fredrik's code shows), you'll be using the bitmap obtained by calling `DrawToBitmap`.

Don't waste too much time making this work. Version 2 of the app will need to implement *proper*, scalable printing support.

Comment: Thanks for your response @Cody Gray but how do i split the image up into separate images, one for each page. as suggested by Fredrik's code?

Comment: Measure the visible dimensions of your page (the area you can print into), and measure the total dimensions of your image. Then divide the image up into page-sized sections. It will likely not divide evenly, so you'll have some part left over to only fill up a partial last page. @Afolabi